# Why is Wiremock Standalone rejecting my valid JSONPath expression?

Tags: arrays, jsonpath, wiremock-standalone

## Background

I am using `wiremock-jre8-standalone-2.35.0.jar`

I want it to return a 200 response if the incoming request's array contains any values:

```
{
    "field1": "data1",
    "array": [
        {...},
        {...},
         ...
    ],
    "field2": "data2",
    "field3": "data3",
    "field4": "data4",
    "field5": "data5"
}
```

I want it to return a 400 response if the incoming requests' array is empty:

```
{
    "field1": "data1",
    "array": [],
    "field2": "data2",
    "field3": "data3",
    "field4": "data4",
    "field5": "data5"
}
```

Wiremock should match the incoming request against the `"request": {...}` from the below code:

```
{
  "id": "...",
  "request": {
    "urlPattern": "...",
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {...},
      "bodyPatterns": [
        {
          "matchesJsonPath": "$[?(@.length < 1)]"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "status": 400,
    "bodyFileName": "...",
    "headers": {...}
  },
  "uuid": "..."
}
```

## Problem

Wiremock is rejecting my JSONPath expression in the bodyPatterns array:

```
[{"matchesJsonPath":"$[?(@.length < 1)]"}] is not a valid match operation
```

Yet it seems that the expression is valid according to https://jsonpath.com/ :

```
JSONPath
---
$[?(@.length < 1)]


Inputs
---
{
    "field1": "data1",
    "array": [],
    "field2": "data2",
    "field3": "data3",
    "field4": "data4",
    "field5": "data5"
}


Evaluation Results
---
[
  []
]
```

...What gives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what gives:

> ## JSON Path
>
> Deems a match if the attribute value is valid JSON and matches the JSON Path expression supplied. A JSON body will be considered to match a path expression if the expression returns either a non-null single value (string, integer etc.), or a **non-empty object or array**.
>
> - https://wiremock.org/docs/request-matching/

My JSON Path expression returns an empty array, so it cannot be considered to match the path expression.